# Highlight whole query phrase

Tags: solr, highlighting

i am using solr for search and i implemented highlighting feature for my search results.
when i my search string is `ring` it highlight `ring` but when search string is `"gold ring"` than also it highlight only `gold`, where i wanted to highlight whole `gold ring` 
for highlighting i use description field which i got as

```
highlighting ={
        "8252": {
            "text": [
                " and <em>gold</em><em>Ring</em>  design was finely crafted in Japan."
            ]
        },
        "8142": {
            "text": [
                "This <em>elegant</em> <em>Ring</em>  has an Akoya cultured pearl with a band of bezel-set round diamonds making"
            ]
        }
    };
```

Now i am parsing it as

```
$.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i,item){
   var word = highlight[item["UID_PK"]];
   var result="";
   var j=0;
   for (j=0 ;j<=item.text.length;j++)
   {
    result = result+item.text[j]+"<br>";
   }
                                result=result.replace(word,'<em>' + word + '</em>');
});
```

Now how should i parse so that i got `gold ring` highlighted

Answer (score 1):

Have you passed -

```
hl.highlightMultiTerm=true
```

in query parameters? This value tells solr to highlight multi term. Value of this parameter is by default set to `false`. So, you need to make it `true` by passing it with query parameter.

For more reference please visit [Solr Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.highlightMultiTerm).

Comment: as you can see in json i got and <em>gold</em><em>Ring</em>  design was finely crafted in Japan.", putting </em> around both ring and gold. i juss need to parse it so that i could get both highlighted